# webservice + facebook-connect

Tags: django, facebook, web-services, django-piston

I'm working on a project that consist in an IOS App and a webservice written using django-piston. Right now I'm using basic HTTP Auth use the webservice. Any idea of how can i integrate facebook connect to authenticate users to use the webservice?

Regards,
Emmet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if you want to authenticate from your iOS app or your web service.

For the iOS app, you can use the iOS SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/

If you authenticate from here, you should be able to get an authentication token via HTTP if you need to grab information on your web service.  If you post more details I'll try to address them.

Comment: I want to authenticate from my web service.

Comment: Can you describe the workflow?

e.g. User clicks login on iOS device->enters login info which is transferred to server->server authenticats and sends mobile device all information

Comment: Yes, it's the workflow that you described. The user information is stored in the site and it will have dual auth (facebook or user/pass).

Comment: Let me think about the best way to do this and I'll try to get back to you (since the only ways I can think of so far are really bad, insecure ones).

Comment: One more question--do you need the user's Facebook data or is it just for account/auth purposes?